# Looping through time-series data in R

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to:

1) fit arma model on given data

2) obtain forecast for the next day

3) add forecast to the data

4) return to 1)

Code I have written:

```
library(forecast)

dates<- seq(as.Date(today), by="days", length=10)
sim<- rnorm(10)
tsdata<- as.ts(cbind(as.xts(dates),sim))

temp<- tsdata

for(i in 1:10){

    Arma1[i]<-  Arima(temp, order=c(2,0,2))
    fcasts1[[i]]<- forecast(Arma1[i], h=1)  
    fore1[i]<-unlist(fcasts1[[i]]$mean[1])
    temp<- as.ts(rbind(as.xts(temp),fore1[i]))
}
```

This gives me an error:

```
Error in x - fits : non-numeric argument to binary operator
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In Arma1[i] <- Arima(temp, order = c(2, 0, 2)) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
2: In mean.default(x, na.rm = TRUE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but: 1) have you defined `Arma1`? 2) What is the data type of `temp`?

Comment: 1) No, but fore(1-4) are `matrix(NA,ncol=1,nrow=lenthfore)` I don't know how to define it, i.e, maybe part of the problem.  2)temp is 'ts` data.

Comment: The idea is that as the data comes, I add it to the previous data and do the analysis, it is known as online learning.

Comment: @Vic sorry I didn't see your `temp` definition before. You can define `Arma1` as `Arma1 <- list(10)`, then assign/access it with `Arma1[[i]]` in the for loop.

Comment: Still an error :-(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what you want to do and if the timeindex for the forecast-values is correct this way, but the loop in this code should at least work:

```
library(xts)
library(forecast)

dates   <- seq(Sys.Date(), by="days", length=10)
sim     <- rnorm(10)
tsdata  <- xts(sim, order.by = dates)

temp.old <- tsdata
temp    <- tsdata
Arma1   <- list(10)
fcasts1 <- list(10)
fore1   <- list(10)
temp    <- list(10)

for(i in 1:10){
  Arma1[[i]]    <-  Arima(temp.old, order=c(2,0,2))
  fcasts1[[i]]  <- forecast(Arma1[[i]], h=1)  
  fore1[i]      <- unlist(fcasts1[[i]]$mean)
  temp[i]    <- as.xts(fore1[[i]], order.by = dates[i])
}
```

Comment: Well there is something wrong!I get the error :`Error in stats::arima(x = x, order = order, seasonal = seasonal, include.mean = include.mean,  : 
  'x' must be numeric`

Comment: Also in temp I want to add the previous data with the new forecast, in your code temp does not add the tsdata(temp) to the new forecast.

Comment: I updated the code, if you want to add the previous data you could easily do that by merge.xts(temp.old, temp) after calling the function.

Comment: Does not do what I want but at-least the for loop works :-)